# How can I pass executable command as argument to adb shell?

Tags: android, adb

I am getting error while executing the below command:

```
$ sudo adb shell ping `cat /data/my_address.pst`
```

Where my_adress.pst file contains the ip address.

But the same command works fine when executed from the shell.

```
$ sudo adb shell

$ ping `cat /data/my_address.pst`
```

How can i pass executable commands like this? please throw some light on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the ` so it is not interpreted by the shell.

```
adb shell ping \`cat /data/my_address.pst\`
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `cat /data/my_address.pst` command gets executed by local shell so you need to escape the backticks or single quote the whole command. Also you do not need `sudo` and use of `$()` is preferable over backticks:

```
adb shell 'ping $(cat /data/my_address.pst)'
```